# After upgrading 5.4 -> 6: Error »Attempt to read property "group_name" on null«

Tags: templates, upgrade

after upgrading from 5.4.2 to 6.0.6 in the CP I get the error

> Warning Attempt to read property "group_name" on null
> ee/ExpressionEngine/Model/Template/Template.php, line 118
>
> Severity: E_WARNING

What does that mean and how could it be fixed? Main parts of the website (frontend) seem to run ok.

Thanks in advance for any advice!!!

EDIT:
I found that the error appears when I edit a template. Editing the template via CP or via FTP-file works, also creating and deleting template groups. What could this be?

Comment: Don't believe I've seen this one come up before.  Gut reaction is that I would go into the template manager and save a template (which should cause the templates to sync in the system)

Comment: Can you check the "group_name" column of the database table 'exp_template_groups'? Is there any empty value?

Comment: @TomJaeger Thanks for your help - somehow the error has vanished. I edited a template-file via FTP, I am not sure if this was the action that fixed it. Perhaps this indeed did a sync, as you have suggested.

Comment: @ZealousWeb Thanks for this suggestion - there is no empty field in this table. But as you might see in my last comment the error vanished without obvious reason (at least for me).

Comment: @TomJaeger Now I found that the error comes up when I edit a template. Saving one changes nothing … Any other idea?

Comment: What version of PHP & MySQL are you running? @BNetz

Comment: MariaDB 5.5.68 and PHP 7.4.21 (was on 8.0.8 for some days, same error) @TomJaeger